# Bypass incapsula while scraping

Tags: c#, .net, httpwebrequest, webrequest

I'm scraping a website using webbrowser. However, it takes a lot time when it is scraping. I need to just read and get source page codes. Because of that i decided to use Httpwebrequest. First time i could get elements that i want but next time i didn't scrape. The site that i scrape has SSL protection and when i try to scrape i get an error below

```
<html>
<head>
<META NAME="robots" CONTENT="noindex,nofollow">
<script>
(function(){function getSessionCookies(){var cookieArray=new Array();var cName=/^\s?incap_ses_/;var c=document.cookie.split(";");for(var i=0;i<c.length;i++){var key=c[i].substr(0,c[i].indexOf("="));var value=c[i].substr(c[i].indexOf("=")+1,c[i].length);if(cName.test(key)){cookieArray[cookieArray.length]=value}}return cookieArray}function setIncapCookie(vArray){var res;try{var cookies=getSessionCookies();var digests=new Array(cookies.length);for(var i=0;i<cookies.length;i++){digests[i]=simpleDigest((vArray)+cookies[i])}res=vArray+",digest="+(digests.join())}catch(e){res=vArray+",digest="+(encodeURIComponent(e.toString()))}createCookie("___utmvc",res,20)}function simpleDigest(mystr){var res=0;for(var i=0;i<mystr.length;i++){res+=mystr.charCodeAt(i)}return res}function createCookie(name,value,seconds){var expires="";if(seconds){var date=new Date();date.setTime(date.getTime()+(seconds*1000));var expires="; expires="+date.toGMTString()}document.cookie=name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/"}function test(o){var res="";var vArray=new Array();for(var j=0;j<o.length;j++){var test=o[j][0];switch(o[j][1]){case"exists":try{if(typeof(eval(test))!="undefined"){vArray[vArray.length]=encodeURIComponent(test+"=true")}else{vArray[vArray.length]=encodeURIComponent(test+"=false")}}catch(e){vArray[vArray.length]=encodeURIComponent(test+"=false")}break;case"value":try{try{res=eval(test);if(typeof(res)==="undefined"){vArray[vArray.length]=encodeURIComponent(test+"=undefined")}else if(res===null){vArray[vArray.length]=encodeURIComponent(test+"=null")}else{vArray[vArray.length]=encodeURIComponent(test+"="+res.toString())}}catch(e){vArray[vArray.length]=encodeURIComponent(test+"=cannot evaluate");break}break}catch(e){vArray[vArray.length]=encodeURIComponent(test+"="+e)}case"plugin_extentions":try{var extentions=[];try{i=extentions.indexOf("i")}catch(e){vArray[vArray.length]=encodeURIComponent("plugin_ext=indexOf is not a function");break}try{var num=navigator.plugins.length if(num==0||num==null){vArray[vArray.length]=encodeURIComponent("plugin_ext=no plugins");break}}catch(e){vArray[vArray.length]=encodeURIComponent("plugin_ext=cannot evaluate");break}for(var i=0;i<navigator.plugins.length;i++){if(typeof(navigator.plugins[i])=="undefined"){vArray[vArray.length]=encodeURIComponent("plugin_ext=plugins[i] is undefined");break}var filename=navigator.plugins[i].filename var ext="no extention";if(typeof(filename)=="undefined"){ext="filename is undefined"}else if(filename.split(".").length>1){ext=filename.split('.').pop()}if(extentions.indexOf(ext)<0){extentions.push(ext)}}for(i=0;i<extentions.length;i++){vArray[vArray.length]=encodeURIComponent("plugin_ext="+extentions[i])}}catch(e){vArray[vArray.length]=encodeURIComponent("plugin_ext="+e)}break}}vArray=vArray.join();return vArray}var o=[["navigator","exists"],["navigator.vendor","value"],["navigator.appName","value"],["navigator.plugins.length==0","value"],["navigator.platform","value"],["navigator.webdriver","value"],["platform","plugin_extentions"],["ActiveXObject","exists"],["webkitURL","exists"],["_phantom","exists"],["callPhantom","exists"],["chrome","exists"],["yandex","exists"],["opera","exists"],["opr","exists"],["safari","exists"],["awesomium","exists"],["puffinDevice","exists"],["navigator.cpuClass","exists"],["navigator.oscpu","exists"],["navigator.connection","exists"],["window.outerWidth==0","value"],["window.outerHeight==0","value"],["window.WebGLRenderingContext","exists"],["document.documentMode","value"],["eval.toString().length","value"]];try{setIncapCookie(test(o));document.createElement("img").src="/_Incapsula_Resource?SWKMTFSR=1&e="+Math.random()}catch(e){img=document.createElement("img");img.src="/_Incapsula_Resource?SWKMTFSR=1&e="+e}})();
</script>
<script>
(function() { 
var z="";var b="7472797B766172207868723B76617220743D6E6577204461746528292E67657454696D6528293B766172207374617475733D227374617274223B7661722074696D696E673D6E65772041727261792833293B77696E646F772E6F6E756E6C6F61643D66756E6374696F6E28297B74696D696E675B325D3D22723A222B286E6577204461746528292E67657454696D6528292D74293B646F63756D656E742E637265617465456C656D656E742822696D6722292E7372633D222F5F496E63617073756C615F5265736F757263653F4553324C555243543D363726743D373826643D222B656E636F6465555249436F6D706F6E656E74287374617475732B222028222B74696D696E672E6A6F696E28292B222922297D3B69662877696E646F772E584D4C4874747052657175657374297B7868723D6E657720584D4C48747470526571756573747D656C73657B7868723D6E657720416374697665584F626A65637428224D6963726F736F66742E584D4C4854545022297D7868722E6F6E726561647973746174656368616E67653D66756E6374696F6E28297B737769746368287868722E72656164795374617465297B6361736520303A7374617475733D6E6577204461746528292E67657454696D6528292D742B223A2072657175657374206E6F7420696E697469616C697A656420223B627265616B3B6361736520313A7374617475733D6E6577204461746528292E67657454696D6528292D742B223A2073657276657220636F6E6E656374696F6E2065737461626C6973686564223B627265616B3B6361736520323A7374617475733D6E6577204461746528292E67657454696D6528292D742B223A2072657175657374207265636569766564223B627265616B3B6361736520333A7374617475733D6E6577204461746528292E67657454696D6528292D742B223A2070726F63657373696E672072657175657374223B627265616B3B6361736520343A7374617475733D22636F6D706C657465223B74696D696E675B315D3D22633A222B286E6577204461746528292E67657454696D6528292D74293B6966287868722E7374617475733D3D323030297B706172656E742E6C6F636174696F6E2E72656C6F616428297D627265616B7D7D3B74696D696E675B305D3D22733A222B286E6577204461746528292E67657454696D6528292D74293B7868722E6F70656E2822474554222C222F5F496E63617073756C615F5265736F757263653F535748414E45444C3D3234303839313831303338343234373432322C31343334313032313035373436353238383130322C31343539333639393136373936303235393635352C313935393639222C66616C7365293B7868722E73656E64286E756C6C297D63617463682863297B7374617475732B3D6E6577204461746528292E67657454696D6528292D742B2220696E6361705F6578633A20222B633B646F63756D656E742E637265617465456C656D656E742822696D6722292E7372633D222F5F496E63617073756C615F5265736F757263653F4553324C555243543D363726743D373826643D222B656E636F6465555249436F6D706F6E656E74287374617475732B222028222B74696D696E672E6A6F696E28292B222922297D3B";for (var i=0;i<b.length;i+=2){z=z+parseInt(b.substring(i, i+2), 16)+",";}z = z.substring(0,z.length-1); eval(eval('String.fromCharCode('+z+')'));})();
</script></head>
<body>
<iframe style="display:none;visibility:hidden;" src="//content.incapsula.com/jsTest.html" id="gaIframe"></iframe>
</body></html>
```

Here My Code

```
            ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => { return true; };

            string address = string.Format(@"https://www.example.com");

            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(address);
            //request.Proxy = WebProxy.GetDefaultProxy();

                request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.2.12) Gecko/20101026 Firefox/3";
                request.Accept = "Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*;q=0.8";
                request.Accept = "Accept-Language: tr-TR,tr;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3";
                request.Accept = "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br";

                //request.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate;
                request.Headers.Add("Upgrade-Insecure-Requests", "1");
                request.Referer = "https://www.example.com/page.html";
                string strData = "";

            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            System.IO.Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream();
                System.Text.Encoding ec = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8");
                System.IO.StreamReader reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(stream, ec);
                strData = reader.ReadToEnd();
```

HERE REQUEST HEADERS

```
Host: www.example.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:50.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/50.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: tr-TR,tr;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Referer: https://www.example.com/mgrp115.html
Cookie: visid_incap_969915=n/UA1sPWSRqcLHS8izlZl/vJOlgAAAAAQkIPAAAAAACAbNh4AS7Fy71tyrvY4hm5/8klCVy0ZPw6; last_domain_id=26; __utma=185813676.385095112.1480247807.1481740765.1481816400.14; __utmz=185813676.1480247807.1.1.utmcsr=google|utmccn=(organic)|utmcmd=organic|utmctr=(not%20provided); incap_ses_473_969915=lZEeZH8zLDzHexwQH2+QBka5UlgAAAAAiNkwWJCksFcH1rQFP4yccA==; GAMBLINGSESS=mii1g4hdedjjimpatgd1p93gld3b5h8l; nlbi_969915=3CsSHBl0mTjavKlP18U7bQAAAADGlJZO8Hu2ocuraCIlqUwK; __utmb=185813676.16.10.1481816400; __utmc=185813676; docscrollltop=0; live_box_sport_status1=true; __utmt=1
Connection: keep-alive
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
```

HERE RESPONSE HEADERS

```
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Length: 12889
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date: Thu, 15 Dec 2016 17:09:44 GMT
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Last-Modified: Thu, 15 Dec 2016 17:09:44 GMT
Pragma: no-cache
Server: Apache/2.2.22 (Linux/SUSE)
Set-Cookie: last_domain_id=26; expires=Fri, 15-Dec-2017 17:09:44 GMT; path=/; domain=.example.com
Vary: Accept-Encoding
X-Cdn: Incapsula
X-Firefox-Spdy: h2
x-iinfo: 8-44586852-44579876 PNNN RT(1481821783171 0) q(0 0 0 -1) r(1 1) U2
```

Can you help about this problem ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @AlfieGoodacre Of course.

Comment: It was a joke, referring to the fact that this question is un-necessarily huge, take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Your code in the first snippet alone reaches over 6500 characters for us to look over, 3700 of which are a javascript function which could genuinely be causing the issue.

Comment: @AlfieGoodacre my sides have split.

Comment: @AlfieGoodacre let me edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you're being blocked by Incapsula that checks you can run javascript on the tool you're using to send requests. I see three options:

1. Use a thirdparty tool: use htmlagilitypack on github with the method `HtmlWeb.LoadFromBrowser` or this othe project on github incapsula-cracker-py3
2. Build your own tool using workarounds that work on your website. (it's unlikely to be done as a reply on this forum)
3. Scrape the data using a browser engine. Send your request in a browser, save the page and scrape using your work in .net

Comment: @sofsntp can i ask you a question in private message or how can i contact to you sir ? by the way thank you so much for answer

Comment: Your answer makes not sense at all. The first time someone opens a page, the browser send an HTTP GET requests to that server, this doesn't check if it can run JS or not. It's in this process that incapsula blocks the requests, it blocks the bot but not the browsers

Comment: yes sounds more accurate, maybe you can explain us how it blocks bots?